# do i need to install virtualenvwrapper-win for Django

Tags: django

I'm going to use Django for my final project so when i'm following the documentation it mentioned that we need to install virtualenvwrapper-win.Is it must to install virtualenvwrapper-win before installing Django? or not?

Comment: It's best practice to use virtual environments but I don't believe it's required for Django

Comment: You could have found out really easily by trying both ways and seeing what happened. http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/windows/):

"virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper provide a dedicated environment for each Django project you create. While **not mandatory**, this is considered a **best practice** and will save you time in the future when you’re ready to deploy your project."

So my advice to you: just do it:)